# Delete just email attachments

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail

I want to just delete email attachments.

Mainly from gmail accounts, but it would be nice from other accounts too like iCloud.

The idea is to delete de attachments while keeping the mail.

Everything I've tried is painfully slow or manual or both or isn't not really deleting the email but creating a clone without attachments, so you need to remove them after.

Either if I try mail app on macOS or thunderbird (either with our without the [AttachmentExtractor](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/attachmentextractor-continued/)) what I'm getting is a copy of the email without attachment, so I have to manually delete the original one.

Is there nothing out there that just works?

Comment: @E.T. can you briefly state what you need this for: whats your purpose of removing attachments

Comment: @ E.T. The original poster asked about gmail - is that your case? What kind is your originating email server?

Comment: You should be able to delete the attachments with Attachment Extractor, maybe you have not seen some option...  [Here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Attachments_%28Thunderbird%29) they suggest as alternative to create a filter with [FiltaQuilla](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/).

Comment: @Hastur Attachment Extractor seems to duplicate messages rather than delete the attachments, see this question or also the review comments on the addon's listing. that's not useful. i also see reviews that it tends to break with a larger amount of messages, and there's even this note: "NOTICE: It doesn't work properly on newer versions of Thunderbird, as evident by reviews!" so yeah, i don't think this is the way to do it anymore

Comment: @1NN reducing storage for the "Sent" folder

Comment: @harrymc I'm wondering about the best way to do this in thunderbird. i want to migrate providers so best would be a way that works with any IMAP provider

Answer (score 6):

**GMail:** For Gmail, there exists the website
[Unattach](https://unattach.app/?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=delete_attachments)
which is commercial with a limited free license.
For the Free plan, the email address you use to sign in to Unattach
needs to be the same as the email address of your Gmail account
(the password is not shared).

**Thunderbird:** The Thunderbird attachment
[AttachmentExtractor Continued](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/attachmentextractor-continued/)
is a fixed version of the original Add-on "AttachmentExtractor"
which was no longer supported.

It does what you want, but doesn't work for
Thunderbird versions later than Thunderbird 78 (the developer just gave up). To use this extension would require installing an old version of Thunderbird,
which you may find in the
[Thunderbird archives](https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/).
You would need to be careful to disable automatic updates immediately
after the installation.

It doesn't seem to be possible to do this in the latest Thunderbird release.

**Apple Mail:** Another possibility is Apple mail, which allows to select
multiple messages and then do *Message > Remove attachments*.

**Script:** For Python, you will find a script at
[imap size reducer](http://lacinato.com/pub/email/imap_size_reducer.py)
which you could adapt to your needs. For GMail this may require a 2FA-enabled account so you can use App Passwords to circumvent their OAuth2 requirement.

Comment: While it's not the answer I hoped it would be (since it seems to boil down to it's not possible in current Thunderbird or another open e-mail program) it still seems to be accurate, so I guess it makes sense to award the bounty to this one

Comment: For what it's worth for curious people passing through, there is a ticket suggesting the Apple Mail approach for Thunderbird's core: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1762545 But it doesn't seem to have gained much traction so far.

Comment: Thanks for that Apple Mail solution @E.T. that I had missed for some reason.

Comment: @cachius: I moved Unattach to the top, as you wish. No problem.

Comment: @cachius: You could have left your answer.